# How to use scikit learn model from inside sagemaker 'model.tar.gz' file?

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

New to Sagemaker..

Trained a "linear-learner" classification model using the Sagemaker API, and it saved a "model.tar.gz" file in my s3 path. From what I understand SM just used an image of a scikit logreg model.

Finally, I'd like to gain access to the model object itself, so I unpacked the "model.tar.gz" file only to find another file called "model_algo-1" with no extension.

[image: contents of unknown file]

Can anyone tell me how I can find the "real" modeling object without using the inference/Endpoint delpoy API provided by Sagemaker? There are some things I want to look at manually.

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear-Learner is a built in algorithm written using MX-net and the binary is also MXNET compatible. You can't use this model outside of SageMaker as there is no open source implementation for this.